# Unexpected Type Erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I am having an issue with generics and what I presume is type erasure whilst trying to reflect some generic information.

I am using a class based on http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860 to do the reflection, but that isn't the issue.

The code below demonstrates the issue:

```
private <U extends MyClass1> U doSomething(MyClass2<U> p) {
     Class<U> classIWant = null;
     for (Class<?> c : GenericTypeUtils.getTypeArguments(MyClass2.class, p.getClass()))      {
        if (MyClass1.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
            classIWant = c.asSubclass(MyClass1.class);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the line

```
classIWant = c.asSubclass(MyClass1.class);
```

Shows the following error

```
java: incompatible types
  required: java.lang.Class<U>
  found:    java.lang.Class<capture#4 of ? extends MyClass1>
```

And that's really confusing me. U extends MyClass1 and therefore U is a MyClass1.

Obviously there is some piece of type erasure I am not understanding here - can anybody help, please. BTW this is Java 1.7.0_40

Thanks

Conrad Winchester

Comment: You can look up here a bit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: This will not be to do with type erasure. Erasure happens at the end of compilation, whereas your error is during compilation. It will instead a improper use of generics (which I'm not familiar enough with  to help, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

The method `asSubclass()` is implemented like so

```
public <U> Class<? extends U> asSubclass(Class<U> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(this))
        return (Class<? extends U>) this;
    else
        throw new ClassCastException(this.toString());
}
```

with a return type of `Class<? extends U>`. Note, that your `U` and the `U` in the `asSubclass` method are completely unrelated type variables.

So the method `asSubclass()` returns a value declared with the type `Class` of some unknown subtype of `U`, where `U` in this case is `MyClass1`.

You are trying to assign this value to a variable of type `Class` with some **known** subtype of `MyClass1`. The compiler can't guarantee that they match and therefore doesn't allow compilation.

You can cast the returned value if you wish, but may end up getting `ClassCastException` at runtime, if the types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler is unable to guarantee that the `Class` object `c` matches the generic type `U`.  Because of type erasure, it is up to the compiler to guarantee type safety, and ensure that the `Class` coming back from `c.asSubclass` matches `Class<U>`, but it can't.

[The `asSubclass` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) returns a `Class<? extends U>`.  In the `Class` class, `U` represents the type of `Class` passed into `asSubclass`.  When you call it, that is `c`.  But the compiler cannot guarantee that this return type matches your own declared `<U extends MyClass1>`.  They could be different subclasses of `MyClass1`.

If **you** can guarantee that `c.asSubclass` will return a `Class<U>`, then cast it as a `Class<U>`:

```
classIWant = (Class<U>) c.asSubclass(MyClass1.class);
```

You will receive an "unchecked cast" warning.  This is there because the compiler cannot guarantee that is really is a `Class<U>`, but you are saying that it is.  Be careful as this may result in a hard-to-track-down `ClassCastException` elsewhere, even after you return the `U`.  Do this only if you can guarantee the type safety yourself.

Comment: Thank you - I was trying to avoid the unchecked cast exception, but it looks like it is impossible.